# Text classification on CNN model

Tags: python, python-2.7, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network

The problem is i need to load the file which i have in h5 format as below

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['acc'])
classes = model.predict_classes("How is the weather today")
print classes
```

And also i need that percentage value of the prediction to be printed

[Here is the link that i refered to while generating this model and saving the file](https://github.com/jatana-research/Text-Classification/blob/master/CNN.ipynb)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please precise your issue? What exactly is your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I need to be able to get the classes for the given input text ie 0 or 1
And also the percentages of predicting 0 or 1 here..

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-78030f779b96> in <module>()
     15 # img = np.reshape(img,[1,320,240,3])
     16 
---> 17 classes = model.predict_classes("How is the weather today?")
     18 
     19 print classes

AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

This is what i am getting..

Comment: AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Comment: try to use predict() instead of predict_classes()

Comment: AFTER using predict i am getting this error
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: My question to be precise is after loading the saved model I need to be able to take a new text as a query and classify the output as 0 or 1
IN case of images i need to pass the image array but here how do i map the text to the Bag of words and then send the input and get the output please look below for the precise code

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from collections import defaultdict
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='theano'
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Embedding, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')
%matplotlib inline
from pandas import compat
compat.PY3 = True


def clean_str(string):
    string = re.sub(r"\\", "", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'", "", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\"", "", string)
    return string.strip().lower()


MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 1000
MAX_NB_WORDS = 20000
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2


weather_data = np.load('./data/weatherdata.npy')
music_data = np.load('./data/musicdata.npy')
search_data = np.load('./data/searchdata.npy')


print(weather_data.shape)
print(music_data.shape)
print(search_data.shape)
data = np.concatenate((weather_data, music_data), axis=0)
# data = np.concatenate((data, search_data), axis=0)


df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.dropna()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df[0].astype(str).values
df[1].astype(str).values
df.columns = ['message', 'class']
print('Shape of dataset ',df.shape)
print(df.columns)
print('No. of unique classes',len(set(df['class'])))



macronum=sorted(set(df['class']))
macro_to_id = dict((note, number) for number, note in enumerate(macronum))

def fun(i):
    return macro_to_id[i]

df['class']=df['class'].apply(fun)
print(df.head(5))


texts = []
labels = []


for idx in range(df.message.shape[0]):
    text = BeautifulSoup(df.message[idx])
    texts.append(clean_str(str(text.get_text().encode())))

for idx in df['class']:
    labels.append(idx)



tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Number of Unique Tokens',len(word_index))



data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels))
print('Shape of Data Tensor:', data.shape)
print('Shape of Label Tensor:', labels.shape)

indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
data = data[indices]
labels = labels[indices]
nb_validation_samples = int(VALIDATION_SPLIT * data.shape[0])

x_train = data[:-nb_validation_samples]
y_train = labels[:-nb_validation_samples]
x_val = data[-nb_validation_samples:]
y_val = labels[-nb_validation_samples:]



embeddings_index = {}
# f = open('glove.6B.100d.txt',encoding='utf8')
import io
f = io.open('glove.6B.100d.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

print('Total %s word vectors in Glove 6B 100d.' % len(embeddings_index))



embedding_matrix = np.random.random((len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,trainable=True)



sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
l_cov1= Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
l_pool1 = MaxPooling1D(5)(l_cov1)
l_cov2 = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(l_pool1)
l_pool2 = MaxPooling1D(5)(l_cov2)
l_cov3 = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(l_pool2)
l_pool3 = MaxPooling1D(35)(l_cov3)  # global max pooling
l_flat = Flatten()(l_pool3)
l_dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(l_flat)
preds = Dense(len(macronum), activation='softmax')(l_dense)

model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['acc'])

print("Simplified convolutional neural network")
model.summary()
cp=ModelCheckpoint('model_cnn.hdf5',monitor='val_acc',verbose=1,save_best_only=True)



history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),epochs=15, batch_size=2,callbacks=[cp])


from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
# del model  # deletes the existing model

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
# model = load_model('my_model.h5')

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'],'r',linewidth=3.0)
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'],'b',linewidth=3.0)
plt.legend(['Training loss', 'Validation Loss'],fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Epochs ',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Loss',fontsize=16)
plt.title('Loss Curves :CNN',fontsize=16)
fig1.savefig('loss_cnn.png')
plt.show()


fig2=plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['acc'],'r',linewidth=3.0)
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'],'b',linewidth=3.0)
plt.legend(['Training Accuracy', 'Validation Accuracy'],fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Epochs ',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Accuracy',fontsize=16)
plt.title('Accuracy Curves : CNN',fontsize=16)
fig2.savefig('accuracy_cnn.png')
plt.show()



from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='cnn_model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)


from PIL import Image
display(Image.open('cnn_model.png'))


 **The problem is here....
 Now in a new file, I am trying to load the file and predict the classes as below**


from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

model = load_model('my_model.h5')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['acc'])


classes = model.predict_classes("How is the weather today")

print classes
```

This is the code for above..

Comment: If this answers your question then you can accept it on the left side of your answer.